# MaxCDN - shared ssl - invalid certificate?

Tags: ssl, resources, certificate

one problem is really bugging me.

I have a webshop with global customer scope, so I am using the known service "maxcdn.com" with a "pull-zone" to share my images, scripts and similar resources via maxcdn.

Maxcdn gives me a subdomain with that I can access my resources and if I enable "shared-ssl" which I did for my cart-checkout which is SSL-secured I get a slightly different subdomain from them that supports ssl.

I replaced all resources via PHP with wether the non-ssl or ssl variant depending on what the current site's protocol is.

On my own PC this construct works pretty well. However at some colleagues (different location, but same behaviour on all PC's, devices) it tells me the SSL certificate is not valid and it cannot open the page at all (with all browsers).

It says the SSL certificate would be invalid and it shows the certificate of max-cdn would not be compatible with my own page's domain.

--
To cut long story short:

Im using my own ssl-certificate to fetch the website from the webserver and use the maxcdn ssl-certificate to fetch resources such as images and css, javascripts to fetch resources from the CDN.

Is this a setup that should work out of the box, or does the maxcdn certificate needs to be registered in the apache or how can this happen.

Anyone got an idea? Thanks so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I solved it myself.

It turned out that the A-Record change (after disabling the full-site-cache) took time to be updated everywhere in the world (as usual) and people that were unfortunate to have still the old DNS-record ended up with a route over the CDN which caused the SSL-Certificate to be invalid for that target.